# Create polygons (representing boundaries) from lines

Tags: r, polygonize, sf

I received a file of municipality boundaries, where the boundaries are represented as lines.  I would like to convert this to a set of polygons, each representing a municipality.  In other words, from a set of lines, I would like to create the highest number of non-overlapping polygons.

I would like to do this in R (currently using the `sf` package, but could use another).  I *believe* the correct command is `st_polygonize`, however the data does not seem to be extremely high quality, so some of the lines do not exactly touch (for one pair, I calculated the distance between the endpoints as 1.77e-15 meters).  There are also holes in the municipalities.

My questions:

1. Is `st_polygonize` the correct command?  I only have one observation for each line segment, but a single line segment can belong to multiple municipalities.  Whoever created this file seems to have done it in a way so that each line segment belongs to at most 2 municipalities, but I do not know how to verify this.
2. How do I deal with the fact that not all line segments will touch?  `st_polygonize` does not seem to have a tolerance parameter, is there some other command I can use?

This is the file as I received it:
[image]

And here is a closeup, with each line segment in a different color to give an idea:
[image]

**EDIT:**

I solved the tolerance issue via the following:

Use `st_line_sample(line, sample = c(0,1))` to find the endpoints of each line.  I then calculated pairwise distances between all endpoints using `st_distance` and filtered for distances that were greater than 0 and less than a tolerance number.  The next part requires some manual work, but using the filtered distances, one can identify which line segments are misaligned.  I then used `st_snap` to snap these line segments to each other.  With the new snapped line segments, I can then create the polygons as per Spaceman's answer below.

Comment: You might have luck with `sfdct::ct_triangulate(x)` - but it completely depends on what grouping you can give to the resulting triangles, so they can be unioned with st_union(, by_feature = TRUE) together.   I don't think that can work with arcs like you have here

Comment: No, I don't think so - because the triangulation must use the lines in unioned form first. It might be possible to intersect the boundaries of the resulting triangles with the lines, but the fundamental problem is not knowing which lines belong together - I'll be interested if anyone has an sf solution for this!

Comment: Actually, try `st_cast(st_polygonize(st_union(x)))`

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to be what Spacedman is suggesting below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with `nc` borders from the `example(st_read)` code, I'll first make a set of lines like in your data and then put them back together again. So we start with 100 North Carolina polygons in a spatial sf data frame:

```
> dim(nc)
[1] 100  15
```

First, to take them apart, convert to lines and intersect them so the overlaps are gone:

```
> 
> ncl = st_cast(nc, "MULTILINESTRING")
> ncli = st_intersection(ncl$geom)
```

Now I have 338 line segments.

```
> length(ncli)
[1] 338
```

These are an `sfc` vector:

```
> class(ncli)
[1] "sfc_GEOMETRY" "sfc"
```

I can see if they have overlaps by plotting one in black, then plotting the rest over the top in red and seeing the first one isn't plotted:

```
> plot(ncli[2])
> plot(ncli[-2],add=TRUE,col="red",lwd=2)
```

[image]

To reconstruct the polygons, use `st_polygonize` on the union of all the lines and then extract the parts from the returned geometry collection:

```
> ncpoly = st_collection_extract(st_polygonize(st_union(ncli)))
```

This gives us....

```
> length(ncpoly)
[1] 108
```

108 polygons.

We have more polygons than we started with because some of the original 100 features must have been in more than one part, and there's no way of telling that from the lines without extra information. I suspect that holes will appear as extra polygons in this process, so some more processing may be needed. Again there's no way of telling if a hole is a hole or a real feature (is it a city boundary in a region or a hole?) without further information.

I don't know how the tolerance will affect this process in your data. I don't know what will happen if you have lines that cross or extend past edges. Good luck. Often the best solution is to track down polygon versions of the data from the source!

Comment: Thank you!  This seems to more or less work.  It doesn't address the tolerance issue, so I will leave the question open for a bit longer, but this might be an issue that needs to be corrected beforehand through some other processing.

The boundaries are supposed to be at the same administrative level, so I strongly suspect that holes are actually holes.

Comment: I wish there was an original polygon source, but I downloaded this from the government directly.  They represent boundaries over 20 years ago, so it's probably not on their priority list to fix the older boundaries unfortunately.

Comment: After playing around a little, I am going to go with this method.  It does seem to take into account holes, in that it will create holes if there are line segments within a larger polygon.  I also know beforehand how many polygons there *should* be (the shapefile came with dots that are at the center of each polygon) and so far it is creating the correct number of polygons.